# How to break strings into chars that are in upper case in c#

Tags: c#, split, uppercase

I was wondering if it is possible to break a string at the upper letters. For example:

I have the value "ProductName" and I want to show "Product Name". Is there a way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need in third party library!

If the performance is not crucial use

```
string addSpaces(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\w", m => char.IsUpper(m.Value[0]) ? ' ' + m.Value : m.Value).Trim();
}
```

don't forget

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score 0):

If use of third party library is acceptable, look at `Humanizer` project.
https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer#humanize-string

Depending on your need, you may find many other things of use.. The one above is certainly covered, in a nice generally useful package.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: you can make a copy of the string , and then make a regex replace of `[A-Z]` with `.\1` (appending a dot in front of it) and do a `split('.')`

Comment: I already tried this, but if I have "ProductName" the result is an array with the words "Product" and "ame", it removes the letter "N"